# Extract Strings from an HTML file

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, awk

I need an sh script  will get text from an html file I download the file with

```
wget website.com/link_123456789 -O 'testfile.txt'
```

the full contents of that file [are located at this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VbrXHEYd)

But you don't need all of that just the important lines

```
<br>
            <IFRAME style="max-width: 850px;" SRC="http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO width="100%" HEIGHT=450></IFRAME>
            <br><br>
            <p>
```

I need the text`http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html` from the file.

Is there a simple answer to work with other strings to?

Comment: This can be done with perl or python with the Html:Parser module.  But it is off topic on askubuntu. http://stackoverflow.com/ is a better place but they do not do coding requests.  Python example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python Perl example: http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/html_parser.html

Comment: This is technically on-topic here, but we prefer it if you actually put forth some effort to solve your own problem instead of make us to all the work.

Comment: @Zimbinskers sure. Bash works too but it should be 4, 5 lines of code in python(and universal applicable to any html and any tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` and multiple delimiters for `-F`

```
searchfor="vodlocker"
wget -q -O- http://pastebin.com/raw/VbrXHEYd | awk -F'SRC="|"' '/SRC/ && /'"$searchfor"'/  {print $4}'
```

---

*Example output:*

```
$ searchfor="vodlocker"; wget -q -O- http://pastebin.com/raw/VbrXHEYd | awk -F'SRC="|"' '/SRC/ && /'"$searchfor"'/  {print $4}' 
http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html
```

Comment: Sorry it will work BUT the word "vodblocker" in the code defies the last sentence of the question "Is there a simple answer to work with other strings to?"

Comment: @Rinzwind sorry :\

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po 'SRC="\K[^"]+(?=")' testfile.txt
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/.*SRC="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' testfile.txt
```

Both takes the desired string enclosed in double quotes and have `SRC=` in front.

**Example:**

```
% wget -q -O- http://pastebin.com/raw/VbrXHEYd | grep -Po 'SRC="\K[^"]+(?=")'      
http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html

% wget -q -O- http://pastebin.com/raw/VbrXHEYd | sed -nr 's/.*SRC="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'
http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html
```

Comment: I like this one. +1 . And if you really want to make sure you only get iFrame src attributes, can you not also add another grep for "iFrame" first?

Comment: @GTrawo to make it more robust you can just use `^\s*<IFRAME\s.*\sSRC="\K[^"]+(?=")` pattern instead..

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), it's awesome!

```
$ curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/VbrXHEYd | pup 'iframe attr{src}'
```

Result

```
http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, he requested for an interactive shell script, this may be an alternative (assuming that the html is downloaded to your PC). Please, copy the following to Gedit:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Please enter the name of the website (such as vodlocker): "
read site

wget -c $(grep IFRAME ~/Downloads/VbrXHEYd.html | awk '/<IFRAME/ {print $4}' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}')
```

2. Save the file as **somename.sh**.
3. Now, give the file executable permissions:

   ```
   chmod a+x /path/to/somename.sh
   ```
4. Then, run the file as:

   ```
   sh /path/to/somename.sh
   ```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `html2` with `sed`:

```
$ curl -s http://pastebin.com/raw/VbrXHEYd | html2 | sed '/iframe\/@src=/!d;s/^.*src=//'
http://vodlocker.com/embed-wrdlm4dbigu4-850x450.html
```